# Asp .Net Identity 2 - Logging out other sessions (using security stamp) after password update also logs out current session

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I need to immediately invalidate and log out any other logged in sessions when a user changes their password, but allow the active session (who has just updated their password) to remain logged in.

To do this, I'm using the `UpdateSecurityStampAsync(currentUser.Id);` method on the UserManager. All other sessions are successfully logged out, but the active session is also logged out despite the call to `SignInAsync` after updating the security stamp.

The Identity configuration I'm using is as follows:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    { 
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    },
    CookieHttpOnly = true,
    CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
    SlidingExpiration = false,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
});
```

The controller code snippet that is updating the password, updating the security stamp, and supposedly logging the current user back in is:

```
var updateResult = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(currentUser.Id, form.CurrentPassword, form.NewPassword);
if (!updateResult.Succeeded)
{
    //handle update failure
}

_signInManager.AuthenticationManager.SignOut();     

//updating the security stamp invalidates all other sessions
await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(currentUser.Id);

await _signInManager.SignInAsync(currentUser, false, false);
```

Running the code, the password is successfully updated and all sessions are logged out due to the security stamp being updated. But based on other examples I've seen (like this [answer from Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221022/logout-user-from-all-browser-when-password-is-changed)), the code above should refresh the auth cookie and keep the active user logged in.

I've tried different variations of the above code:

- Moving the sign out to after the security stamp update
- Removing the sign out altogether
- Using the  synchronous `SignIn` extension method instead of the async one

all variations produce the same result: The user is forced to log back in after changing their password.

Is there a configuration error or something else that I've overlooked?

EDIT: 
I've unintentionally fixed the problem by adding in the `DefaultAuthenticationTypes` into the `SignOut` call.

The relevant code now reads as:

```
//updating the security stamp invalidates all other sessions
await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(currentUser.Id);
_signInManager.AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(currentUser, false, false);
```

However, if anyone could explain why the Authentication type is important in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Don't set validation interval to TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0), as that causes the sign in cookie to be issued immediately, set it to something like 1 second instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "that causes the sign in cookie to be issued immediately"? Isn't this about validation? I would assume, that a 0 validation interval would mean that the cookie is validated on every request.