# ASP.NET Identity 2 with Google login... Logout doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-identity-2, google-signin

I want to be able to logout the currently logged in user, especially in the use case of current user closes browser, opens a new browser, heads to the login page.

Here is what I've been trying...

```
private ActionResult DoLogout()/// check this out https://dzone.com/articles/catching-systemwebowin-cookie the sytem.web cookie monster
{
    var AuthenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut( DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie );
    Session.Abandon();

    var user = UserManager.FindByName( User.Identity.Name );

    if (user != null)
    {
        UserManager.UpdateSecurityStamp( user.Id ); // remove the old cookie so it can't be reused to re-log in - EWB
    }

     AuthenticationManager.SignOut();

    ClearCookies();

    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut( DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie );// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999318/owin-authentication-signout-doesnt-seem-to-remove-the-cookie - stralos s answer
                                                                                                            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675904/asp-net-identity-2-logging-out-other-sessions-using-security-stamp-after-pa

    AuthenticationManager.SignOut( DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie );

    return Redirect("https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=https://"+ Url.Action( "Index", "Home", new { target = "_blank" } ) ); //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515518/asp-net-identity-external-login-wont-log-out - f belihocine answer

  }
```

but when I log back in this code gets called

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

if (loginInfo == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("LogOut");    // <--- here
}
```

Because the user is in a broken state, because I think ASP.net is logged out, but Google is still logged in....

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what finally did the trick

```
  Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut( DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie );// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999318/owin-authentication-signout-doesnt-seem-to-remove-the-cookie - stralos s answer
  Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut( DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie );                                                                                                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675904/asp-net-identity-2-logging-out-other-sessions-using-security-stamp-after-pa
```

I noticed that most places used app cookie, but in a few it was external.. .I converted all to app cookie and it stopped working, then I tried this next.

Here is the code in StartupAuth where you can see both cookies are being used

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(
            new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 1 ),
                CookieName = "SP3GGS-ID2-cookie",
                //CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always, // TODO: turn this on for prod/qa so only ssl is allowed - EWB - per https://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 1 ),
                        regenerateIdentity: ( manager, user ) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync( manager )
                        )
                }, 
            });            
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);// HERE EWB
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call Google API to get this done , please see this for more information [ASP.net identity - external login - won't log out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515518/asp-net-identity-external-login-wont-log-out)

Comment: I was already calling the Google logout URL (see last line of code sample in question) and it wasn't working.. I needed to call the External cookie in OWIN, not the Google Sesison, thanks for trying to help though!