# How to logout all users in ASP.NET Core cookie authentication?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC with CookieAuthentication. Is there a way I can sign all users out at once? I tried resetting IIS - didn't work. I tried deleting all the users' sessions (I'm using a database for session storage) - didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: To logout all users, the encryption key may be changed or authentication cookie may be renamed.

Comment: @Zygimantas check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36050939/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi: Identity server is used in your link. The question does not mention it, just plain simple cookie authentication.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CookieAuthenticationOptions.SessionStore` Property, to store identity information in server side so you can clear it all when you need.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    MemoryCacheTicketStore memoryCacheTicketStore = new MemoryCacheTicketStore();
    services.AddSingleton<MemoryCacheTicketStore>(memoryCacheTicketStore);

    services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.SessionStore = memoryCacheTicketStore;
    });
}

public class SessionController : Controller
{
    private readonly MemoryCacheTicketStore memoryCacheTicketStore;

    public SessionController(MemoryCacheTicketStore memoryCacheTicketStore)
    {
        this.memoryCacheTicketStore = memoryCacheTicketStore;
    }

    public Task ClearAllSession()
    {
        return memoryCacheTicketStore.ClearAll();
    }
}

public class MemoryCacheTicketStore : ITicketStore
{
    private const string KeyPrefix = "AuthSessionStore-";
    private IMemoryCache _cache;

    public MemoryCacheTicketStore()
    {
        _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
    }

    public async Task ClearAll()
    {
        _cache.Dispose();
        _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
    }

    public async Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var key = KeyPrefix + guid.ToString();
        await RenewAsync(key, ticket);
        return key;
    }

    public Task RenewAsync(string key, AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions();
        var expiresUtc = ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
        if (expiresUtc.HasValue)
        {
            options.SetAbsoluteExpiration(expiresUtc.Value);
        }
        options.SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)); // TODO: configurable.

        _cache.Set(key, ticket, options);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<AuthenticationTicket> RetrieveAsync(string key)
    {
        AuthenticationTicket ticket;
        _cache.TryGetValue(key, out ticket);
        return Task.FromResult(ticket);
    }

    public Task RemoveAsync(string key)
    {
        _cache.Remove(key);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With CookieAuthentication, the cookie is simply an encrypted string containing the user's name, roles, and auxilliary data.  In short, it identifies the *user*, not the *session.*  Killing sessions does not invalidate the cookie.

That being said, you can stuff a session identifier or other token in the cookie's auxiliary data, and then validate that during the authentication process.  An example of someone trying to this can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72479/Coupling-ASP-NET-Session-State-With-Forms-Authenti).

Another option is instead of invalidating sessions you can temporarily disable users in your user repository.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652118/disable-user-in-aspnet-identity-2-0) is an example using ASPNET Identity 2.0.

A third (nuclear) option is to change the [machine key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550210/uses-for-machinekey-in-asp-net) on all web servers, which will render any old forms authentication cookies unreadable, forcing all users to sign on again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where the app needs to react to back-end user access changes. The authentication cookie will secure the application, but, remains valid for the lifetime of the cookie. With a valid cookie, the end-user will not see any changes until they log out or the cookie expires.

The most suitable solution in ASP.NET Core, to validate authentication cookie changes is through [Cookie Authentication Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-8.0#react-to-back-end-changes). The validation event will perform back-end lookups from identity claims in the cookie. This event extends `CookieAuthenticationEvents`. Here we override the `ValidatePrincipal` method.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using System.Security.Claims;

public class RevokeAuthenticationEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public RevokeAuthenticationEvents(IMemoryCache cache, ILogger<RevokeAuthenticationEvents> logger)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override Task ValidatePrincipal(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
    {
        var userId = context.Principal.Claims.First(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

        if (_cache.Get<bool>("revoke-" + userId))
        {
            context.RejectPrincipal();

            _cache.Remove("revoke-" + userId);
            _logger.LogDebug("{Message}", "Access has been revoked for: " + userId + ".");
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

To have `IMemoryCache` set by DI, put `AddMemoryCache` inside the `ConfigureSerices` method in the `Startup` class. Calling `context.RejectPrincipal()` has an immediate effect and kicks users back out to Login to get a new authentication cookie.

Register the event inside the `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup` class.

```
options.EventsType = typeof(RevokeAuthenticationEvents);
services.AddScoped<RevokeAuthenticationEvents>();
```

Now you can logout users by setting the cache inside the corresponding Method of your Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using System.Security.Claims;

public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUsersService _usersService;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public AuthenticationController(IUsersService usersService, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _usersService = usersService;
        _cache = cache;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Logout()
    {
        // Logout currently logged in user
        var principal = HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        var userId = principal?.Claims.First(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

        _cache.Set("revoke-" + userId, true);

        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task LogoutAll()
    {
        // Fetch users from database
        var users = await _usersService.GetAllUsersAsync();

        // Logout all users
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            var userId = user.Id;
            _cache.Set("revoke-" + userId, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this relies on in-memory persistence which gets set in the controller action methods. Keep in mind that this [type of event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-8.0#react-to-back-end-changes) runs once per every request, so you want to use an efficient caching strategy.

### Login

Make sure you add the claim inside the action method responsible for login in your Controller.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    // Set the user id
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId)
};

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
    authProperties);
```

For more information see [Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-8.0#create-an-authentication-cookie).

Answer (score -2):

it's very simple.
change the login cookie name

in startup.cs, change the default name to anything.

```
 options.Cookie.Name = "NewName";
```

**Complete Example:**

```
  services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "NewName"; //<-- Here
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
              ...
                options.Events = options.Events ?? new CookieAuthenticationEvents();
                var onForbidden = options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied;
                var onUnauthorized = options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin;
                options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (context) => OnRedirect(context, onForbidden, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
                options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = (context) => OnRedirect(context, onUnauthorized, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            });
```