# How to set Invalid Cookies in Asp.Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, session-cookies, identity

we have one user with this flow :
User login in Google Chrome browser.
User Login in Edge Browser.

User Change his password with Chrome browser, and his cookie set again in this browser.
User still has un-changed cookie in Edge browser. if refresh the browser, I'll face with this error , and only with cleaning cookies user could see the website :

**502 - web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.**

after searching about this issue, find out I should set cookie invalid after changing password, so use this

```
        services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
        {
            // enables immediate logout, after updating the user's stat.
            options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
        });
```

and :

```
await userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
```

but it doesn't work. what should I do with this problem?
**I want to clear invalid cookie or somehow redirect user to login page**

Comment: try to make force log out after user changing his password

Comment: how? force logout from all browser?

Comment: this will help you for sure   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221022/logout-user-from-all-browser-when-password-is-changed